# Can removal of internal organs (such as in hysterectomy) affect the posture of the body or the stomach?

Tags: posture, removal, uterus, internal-organs

A friend of mine had a partial hysterectomy operation (her womb was removed but the ovaries were left in place).

She has had some weight gain in her abdominal area since then. She feels that some of this is a protrusion directly caused by the removal of internal organs (as opposed to hormonal changes and such), in that the removal of organs left a gap that caused the stomach to lay differently.

Can removal of internal organs affect the posture of the body, or cause the stomach to protrude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say consult a doctor to confirm the problem. Removal of the [Uterus usually doesn't cause to much of a shift,](http://www.upmc.com/patients-visitors/education/womens-health/Pages/hysterectomy.aspx) but I am sure there are a very few instances when it does.

> The uterus typically takes up a very small space in the abdomen or
>   pelvis. After a hysterectomy, the other abdominal organs shift
>   slightly to fill the space. During the surgery, ligaments that helped
>   to support the uterus are connected to the top of the vagina to
>   support it and help keep it in its normal position.

A [pelvic exenteration](http://www.cancer.ca/en/cancer-information/diagnosis-and-treatment/tests-and-procedures/pelvic-exenteration/?region=on) would be a time when organ removal defintely would affect you a lot more.

### Helpful:

- [After a hysterectomy, what happens to the extra space created inside the woman's body?](https://www.quora.com/After-a-hysterectomy-what-happens-to-the-extra-space-created-inside-the-womans-body-Do-other-organs-move-Are-there-risks-arising-from-this-space)

Basically, the Uterus is not that big so the bladder and other structures fill the void. Above link shows pics.

[Uterus size:](http://m.newhealthadvisor.com/Normal-Size-of-Uterus.html)

> The normal size of uterus at this time is 7.6cm x 4.5cm x 3cm
>   (length, width, thickness)